# How to center first div, and have second div right next to it using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

So, I have a parent div with two childs. I need the first in the center, and the second at the right after some d distance. Can't seem to find how to do it with flexbox.

```
<--------------------[First]-d-[Second]------------->
                        |
                      Center
```

What worked is centering the first div, and give an absolute position and right distance to the second. But I would like to do it with only flexbox (if possible).

I've tried setting a left-margin with percentage (47% for example), but it is not consistent with different screen sizes and the first div go out of center.

Auto margins and justify-content also cause the first div to not be in the center. (Since it centers both divs).

Edit: I want the first centered div to push all other divs that might be after.

Comment: What is wrong with your first technique (making second element absolute)?

Comment: @Kalnode let's say I don't have only two, but more divs, And I want all to be next to each other after the first centered div. The absolute solution wouldn't work well there, I would need to calculate fixed distances for each of them, which doesn't really scale well.

Comment: IMHO it sounds like you need to be using `grid` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin` if the width is known beforehand:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

#first {
  margin-left: calc(var(--width) + var(--gap));
}

#second {
  width: var(--width);
}
```

Try it:

```css
:root {
  --gap: 10px;
  --width: 50px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

#first {
  margin-left: calc(var(--width) + var(--gap));
}

#second {
  width: var(--width);
}


/* Demo only */

#container {
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

#first {
  width: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
}

#second {
  background: #ccc;
}

#center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

...or `grid` with its powerful `grid-template-columns`:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

#first {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

Try it:

```css
:root {
  --gap: 10px;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

#first {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}


/* Demo only */

#container {
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

#first {
  width: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
}

#second {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50px;
}

#center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also cheat a little. Create a third empty `div` on the left, and then use `space-around` or `center` with a `gap`.

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

or

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't do it, in the first solution the space between divs is evenly distributed, and what I want is the second div next to the centered (with some margin space). In the second case, both divs would be centered, that means that the first div is not in the absolute center.